# I94 extension after passport renewal

Tags: india

I recently got my passport renewed. My i94 expires this September, 2020. I need to apply for an EAD, so I need a valid i94 as well. What are my options? I am on an L2 visa living in Illinois. The nearest border crossing is way long from here. I have 2 children and feel that traveling with them during covid is risky (kids have valid i94 until 2022). Please give me a solution.

Comment: What is your current status?

Comment: I am in L2 visa.. sorry I didn't mention

Comment: I was in the same boat, passport renewed and I94 expiring in Oct. I applied for extension by filling I-539 and paying $455. Just hoping it gets approved before Oct.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to leave the US and re-enter, the alternative is to apply for L2 Extension of Status by filing form I-539. It costs $455 and takes several months to approve. I am not sure whether you can apply for an L2 EAD renewal along with the Extension of Status.

Comment: It is permitted to file the I-765 concurrently with the I-539. See https://www.uscis.gov/forms/all-forms/filing-form-i-765-with-other-forms